# How to access carousel bootstrap4 active slide to initialize an event

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am trying to call a new countUp.js object on an active bootstrap 4 carousel slide No.2 (position).
I know how to start an event after the slide has changed (finished), like this: `$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {...}`

like here documented: [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)
but how can I invoke the object (method) **only** on the particular slide No.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After back and forth i found i was missing the `relatedTarget.id` so i used this switch statement to get it done, i believe there is also a way with the answer above, but this worked for me:

```
$('#startPageCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (ev) {
  var id = ev.relatedTarget.id; // needed to get the id of the element
  switch (id) {
    case "3":
      // do something the id is 3
      var options = {
        useEasing: true,
        useGrouping: true,
        separator: ',',
        decimal: '.',
      };
      var stat1 = new CountUp('stats1', 0, numberOfPosts, 0, 5.5, options);
      var stat2 = new CountUp('stats2', 0, numberOfPosts, 0, 5.5, options);
      var stat3 = new CountUp('stats3', 0, numberOfPosts, 0, 5.5, options);
      var stat4 = new CountUp('stats4', 0, numberOfPosts, 0, 5.5, options);

      if (!stat1.error && !stat2.error && !stat3.error && !stat4.error) {
        stat1.start();
        stat2.start();
        stat3.start();
        stat4.start();
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the easily editable solution

```
let currentId = 0, 
    seekedId = 3;
$('.carousel-item').each(function(){
    if(currentId == seekedId){
        $(this).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
            console.log('only on 3rd element');
        });
    }else{
        currentId += 1;
    }
});
```

using jquery eq:

```
$('.carousel-item:eq( 2 )').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
    console.log('3rd element do something');
});
```

Comment: unfortunately had a hard time getting the id, finally i used a switch statement and relatedTarget.id from the bootstrap docs, but thanks anyway